# Automatically Delete Files From Downloads Folder Daily Unless Tagged With "Keep"?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, automation, finder-tag

How can I automate the deletion of files from my downloads folder but keep files I've tagged with "Keep"? I've been able to use Automator to delete files daily, but I can't work with tags in Automater. Most likely this requires AppleScript (I'm fairly new to AppleScript). I've created an AppleScript to delete files from Downloads folder, but it's not working (I can't tell if it's a permissions issue), and I'm lost on how file tags/labels work in AppleScript.

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        delete (every item of folder "/Users/wheel58m/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads")
    end tell
    
on error
    display dialog ("Error. Couldn't Move the File") buttons {"OK"}
end try
```

Any documentation or resources is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Automatically Delete Files From Downloads Folder Daily Unless Tagged With “Keep”?

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be used in a *shell script* with an `/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang*, or an **AppleScript** *script/application*, or a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow* to delete any *file* in the `targetFolder` that does not have a custom "Keep" **Tag** set in **Finder**:

```applescript
-- # targetFolder can be either an HFS path or a POSIX path,
-- # "path:to:target:folder:" or "/path/to/target/folder"
-- # 
-- # Change the value of targetFolder from "/path/to/target/folder"
-- # to the appropriate fully qualified pathname in either form.

set targetFolder to "/path/to/target/folder"


-- # The remaining code should not need to be modified, 
-- # unless the mdfind query needs to be changed.

set targetFolderPOSIXpath to ¬
    the quoted form of ¬
        the POSIX path of targetFolder

set shellCMD to {¬
    "mdfind -onlyin", space, targetFolderPOSIXpath, space, ¬
    "'! kMDItemKind == Folder && ! kMDItemUserTags == Keep'"} ¬
    as string

set posixFilesToDelete to ¬
    paragraphs of ¬
    (do shell script shellCMD)

set filesToDelete to {}
repeat with thisFile in posixFilesToDelete
    set thisFile to POSIX file thisFile as alias
    set the end of filesToDelete to thisFile
end repeat

if filesToDelete is not {} then ¬
    tell application "Finder" to ¬
        delete filesToDelete
```

<sup>**Note:** Scroll as necessary to see remaining *code*.</sup>

---

**Notes:**

- As I do not have the *target folder* mentioned in the OP, I could not test for any permissions issues that may need addressing in: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**
- The *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested and work for me without issue in **macOS Catalina** using a temporary *folder* created within my **Home** *folder* while adding *files* and *folders* to it and tagging only some *files* with a custom "Keep" **Tag** in **Finder**.
- As to "Automatically Delete Files" there are a number of different ways to accomplish this depending on how the *example* **AppleScript** *code* is used. Used as an **AppleScript** *shell script* or *application* it can be scheduled to run at whatever time you'd like, using any of several different methods.

  - As an **AppleScript** *application* using: **Calendar**
  - As an **AppleScript** *shell script* using: `launchd` or `cron`

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the detail. I was able to get this working perfectly! I'll create an AppleScript application to run with Calendar and add error handling with the documentation you mentioned. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @wheel58m, Really shouldn't need any additional _error handling_ and the note at the bottom is _boiler plate_ I usually always add just to cover the bases, so to speak.  The _code_ as is was actually tested as an **AppleScript** _application_ scheduled in **Calendar** and worked without issues. That's not to say you can't customize the _code_ to fit your needs. Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, tags are still called "labels" in Applescript. Finder will return a different "label index" depending on a file's tag/label.

```
tell application "Finder" to get label index of file "path:to:file"
```

When a file has no tags, this returns "0". When a file has a "red" tag, it returns 2, and when it has a "yellow" tag, it returns 3. When a file has a "red" *and* a "yellow" tag, it... still returns 3.

This all feels kind of weird/fragile, but if you can't find a better way to do this (!), I'd do some experimenting to find the "label index" of your `keep` tag, and then check for that in your code.

Comment: The problem is any **Finder** _item_ with a custom **Tag**  its `label index` _property_ will return `0` just like any **Finder** _item_ without a  **Tag**. So you cannot differentiate **Finder** _items_ with a "Keep" **Tag** or **Finder** _items_ without a  **Tag** by using its `label index` _property_ !

Comment: I've no clue how this all works, but I found many references to tags as distinct from labels.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24599917 https://stackoverflow.com/q/19784075 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7741109 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/131258/85275

Comment: Just to add to my first comment, sorry, I accidentally left out "with no color assigned" as in...  The problem is any **Finder** _item_ with a custom **Tag** with no color assigned, its `label index` _property_ will return `0` just like any **Finder** _item_ without a **Tag**. Sorry for any confusion. --- IMO The safest way to achieve the goal of the OP using native **macOS** utilities is to focus on the `kMDItemUserTags` _metadata attribute_ using an `mdfind` _query_, which is not **AppleScript** but can be used in conjunction with it to achieve the goal.

Comment: RE: "From what I can tell, tags are still called "labels" in Applescript." --  From the **AppleScript** dictionary for **Finder**... "**label** _n_ : (NOT AVAILABLE YET) A Finder label (name and color)", so while `label` is mentioned it is not yet, as of **macOS Big Sur**, usable by a _query_ on a **Finder** _item_, like `label index` would be, and would return an error, e.g. "Can’t get label ..."

Answer (score 0):

The following AppleScript is a working version of the code you posted, if you replace `<SystemDrive>` and `<username>` with the names of your system drive and username, respectively.

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        delete (every item of folder "<SystemDrive>:Users:<username>:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~CloudDocs:Downloads")
    end tell
    
on error
    display dialog ("Error. Couldn't Move the File") buttons {"OK"}
end try
```

See [Apple's documentation on working with files and folders in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html).

I couldn't find any mention of tags in AppleScript's Finder library but [Howard Oakley states](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/10/31/finder-tags-commonplace-metadata/) that they *can* be added with AppleScript, hence they should be accessible, perhaps as labels as @Wowfunhappy suggests. You might need to install and learn how to use `tag`, as mentioned in the same article.

Comment: How does the **AppleScript** _code_ in your answer keep from deleting the _files_ which have a "Keep" **Tag**? It doesn't! The title of the question asks: "Automatically Delete Files From Downloads Folder Daily Unless Tagged With “Keep”?"

Comment: I meant that it will do what the code posted in the question is meant to do. Then I explained how he might go about finding out how to access tags.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to get the script to delete the files now. I just needed to add the drive name and replace "/" with the colon ":". Just trying to figure out the tags, haha.