# Shell scripting: Select folder based on part of file name

Tags: bash, filesystem, folders, script, command-line

## My project

I'm creating a bash shell script to execute from the Terminal. Its purpose is to archive lots and lots of project folders. Each folder follows a prescribed nomenclature: `[YYYY.MM.DD] - Medium - Client - Project name - details--details - JobNumber`. For example: `[2006.02.01] - Print - Development - Appeal I - Kids Art Show Insert - D0601-11`. These projects are currently one folder. **I want to sort them into folders by Client name.** There are 7 (internal) clients, so I'm using the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Go to the Completed Projects folder.
cd /Volumes/communications/Projects/Completed\ Projects/

# Find a folder with a specified string (e.g. "Academics") in its name.
# Move (not copy) the folder to its corresponding sub-folder of the Archived Projects folder. (e.g. /Academics)

for folder in *; do
    if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
        if [[ "$folder" == *Academics* ]]; then
            echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → Academics...";
            mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/Academics/
        fi
        elif [[ "$folder" == *Admissions* ]]; then
            echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → Admissions...";
            mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/Admissions/
        fi
        elif [[ "$folder" == *Alumni* ]]; then
            echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → Academics...";
            mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/Alumni/
        fi
        elif [[ "$folder" == *Communications* ]]; then
            echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → Academics...";
            mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/Communications/
        fi
        elif [[ "$folder" == *Development* ]]; then
            echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → Academics...";
            mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/Development/
        fi
        elif [[ "$folder" == *President* ]]; then
            echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → Academics...";
            mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/President/
        fi
        elif [[ "$folder" == *Student\ Life* ]]; then
            echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → Academics...";
            mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/Student\ Life/
        fi
    else #Folders that don't match the pattern prompt the use to move them by hand.
        echo "$folder does not have a Department name. Move it by 
done
```

## My problem

My script would mis-parse and mis-file a project named `[2006.03.01] - Print - Development - Academics and Accreditation - D0601-08`. It would read "Academics" before it ever got to the conditional for the client "Development". As a result, it would be files into "Academics". And I'd have to pick it back out by hand!

## My system's advantage

My colleagues and I have been scrupulous about our nomenclature (described above). I know that the Client name falls in between the 2nd and 3rd hyphens.

## My question

How to leverage my system's advantage to solve my problem? I want this script to match only the part of the folder name that comes **after the first two hyphens and before the third hyphen,** i.e., I only want this script to search the Client "field" in the folder name. I keep thinking "regular expressions" but have no idea how to implement them.

*Note: I prefer for a solution to augment my current script, rather than replace it. I arrived at it via @patrix on this site and his idea circumvented some errors.*

Comment: [Why bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)? If I could give you a script in another language that worked would you be okay with that?

Comment: Good question, @IanC. Bash because it's all I know how to use with the Terminal in Mac OS X.

Comment: bash is a limited language as Unix OSs now come with languages like perl python etc I would write anything longer than 3-4 lines in that as bash is not well behaved

Comment: `*- Academics -*` ?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: I know what you ask, and this is a comment, not an answer. Have you thought of using labels in combination with find? It might be just what you want. Check @grgarside http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131164/how-to-tag-files-with-finder-tags-using-parts-of-a-file-name/131166#131166

Comment: None of the answers we've given are particularly Mac-specific at this point. Would you consider using something like [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) to manage the folder?

Comment: I'd consider Hazel but I'm trying to learn to write scripts. Also Hazel seems ideal for local storage, but I'm working with a network share running Windows 2012 Server. @IanC.

Answer (score 3):

How about using awk with the field separator option -F  and separate the field by the hyphen. Then get the third field.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code to use the result returned from the awk to place the destination folder. This saves on a lot of code. And also used the separator " - " as Ian C pointed out in the comments.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Go to the Completed Projects folder.
cd /Volumes/communications/Projects/Completed\ Projects/

# Find a folder with a specified string (e.g. "Academics") in its name.
# Move (not copy) the folder to its corresponding sub-folder of the Archived Projects folder. (e.g. /Academics)

for folder in *; do
    if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
        thirdfield=`echo "$folder" | /usr/bin/awk -F ' - ' '{print $3}'`;
        echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → $thirdfield...";
        mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/"$thirdfield"/"$folder"    
    fi     
done
```

I have also added /"$folder" at the end of the move so the folder itself is moved. you can change this if thats not what you want by removing the "$folder" from the end of the mv command.

---

You can also cross check against an array of the 7 names so only those folders that correspond will be moved. ( you can insert an else statement where needed)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Go to the Completed Projects folder.
cd /Volumes/communications/Projects/Completed\ Projects/

# Find a folder with a specified string (e.g. "Academics") in its name.
# Move (not copy) the folder to its corresponding sub-folder of the Archived Projects folder. (e.g. /Academics)

# Array of names to check against
ArrayName=(Academics Admissions  Alumni Communications Development President Student)

for folder in *; do
    if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
        thirdfield=`echo "$folder" | /usr/bin/awk -F ' - ' '{print $3}'`;

        for var in "${ArrayName[@]}"; do
            # Only move the folder if its key name exists in the arrary
            if [ "${var}" = "$thirdfield" ]; then
                echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → $thirdfield...";
                mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/"$thirdfield"/"$folder"   
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: `awk` is definitely the way to go if this must absolutely stay in `bash`.

Comment: Also I'd split on `' - '` instead of just `'-'`

Comment: @IanC. Good point I will Adjust that. I actually just got up with the thought in my head of using the thiredfield as a var in the destination folder so that will help. ( And I see while I was asleep you did just that :-)  )

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to get this done in `bash` and friends (you could really knock yourself out using `sed` or `awk`). A rather simple way is to use `cut` to get the name of the folder

```
if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
    target=$(echo $(echo "$folder" | cut -d- -f 3))
    echo "Archiving $folder to Archived Projects → $target...";
    mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/$target/
fi
```

The `$(echo $(echo ... ))` is a lazy approach to get rid of the leading/trailing space (because `cut` doesn't support multi-char delimiters).

---

If you *want to* knock yourself out with `sed` you can use

```
    target=$(echo "$folder" | sed -n 's/^[^\-]*-[^\-]*- \([^\-]*\) -.*/\1/p')
```

instead of `cut`. This only works if the target folder name doesn't contain a `-` itself.

---

Instead of pattern matching you could also use a shell function to encapsulate most of the complexity.

```
#!/bin/bash

function checkAndMove() {
    if [[ "$1" == *$2* ]]; then
        echo "Archiving $1 to Archived Projects → $2...";
        mv "$1" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/$2/
    fi
}

cd /Volumes/communications/Projects/Completed\ Projects/

for folder in *; do
    if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
        checkAndMove Academics
        checkAndMove Admissions
        ...
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can learn bash you can certainly learn a better language like Ruby to solve this problem.

There is massive room for improvement in what I'm posting, but here's some basic Ruby that does your re-categorizations for you. Some advantages to this Ruby code over your bash code:

1. It handles the addition of new `client` fields and automatically moves them according to your preferred archiving scheme
2. It makes intermediate directories if they don't exist
3. It halts if there's a problem moving a directory which implies that if it doesn't halt, everything moved successfully

And of course, if you ask me, it's infinitely more read-able and expandable. If you can learn bash, Ruby is much of a stretch and you'll find you can automate better with it than you can with bash.

I tried to stay close to how your bash works so it'd look familiar. As you can see, it's quite a bit terser than that bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fileutils'

SOURCE = '/Users/ianc/tmp/ad'
DESTINATION = '/Users/ianc/tmp/ad-new'

Dir.chdir(SOURCE)

Dir['**'].each do |f|
  if File.exists?(f) && File.directory?(f)
    # Format: [YYYY.MM.DD] - Medium - Client - Project name - details--details - JobNumber
    date, medium, client, project, details, job_number = f.split(' - ', 6)
    if client
      destination = File.join(DESTINATION, client)
      FileUtils.mkpath destination if !File.exists?(destination)
      destination = File.join(destination, f)
      source = File.join(SOURCE, f)
      puts 'Moving: ' + source + ' --> ' + destination
      FileUtils.mv(source, destination)
    else
      puts 'Skipping: ' + f
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So you're saying I can execute a Ruby script from the Mac OS X terminal just like I would a bash script? (I'm clearly not a programmer—yet.) And if so, what would I type into the command line to execute said Ruby script?

Comment: Save that to a file, just like your shell script, and then set the execute bit on it by typing: `chmod +x <file name>`. Now just type the name of the file and it'll run. That magic first line `!#/usr/bin/env ruby` tells the OS to run the script using Ruby.

Comment: And the Mac has Ruby out of the box? @IanC.

Comment: Yes. Ruby is there out of the box.

Comment: Is this script likely to break in the event that it encounters a format different that the one described in the #comment? The `details--details` section varies widely from folder to folder. It often includes special characters like `[ ] -`. @IanC.

Comment: It splits on all instances of ' - ' -- so anything as long as there isn't an occurrence of the pattern ' - ' within in the `details--details` section of the name, it won't break.

Comment: Bummer. Sometimes it does have ' - ' within the `details--details` section. Should I specify that above?